# Two different s3-upload tasks in SBT?

Tags: sbt

I'm using the [sbt-s3 plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-s3) to upload my project JAR and its dependencies to S3:

```
mappings in upload := Seq(
  (Path(crossTarget.value) / s"${name.value}-deps.zip", s"${name.value}-deps.zip"),
  ((packageBin in Compile).value, s"${name.value}.jar")
)
```

The `*-deps.zip` is generated by another task.

However, the dependencies don't change as often as the application `.jar`, so I'd like to have a task to upload just the .jar and another one to upload both the jar and the dependencies. Can anyone help?